# How to start and run a command in X server from remote Terminal?

Tags: xserver

I need to run a command in Ubuntu Terminal on my computer. I am connected to the other computer by SSH. I need to be able to start X server from my remote computer (without being able to interact with X server once it has started) and run a script in X server once it starts.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Are you using any login manager (the login screen)? In default Ubuntu the X session is managed by LightDM. Are you using anything custom or just want to start a regular Ubuntu login screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting X server using [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). It will keep it running as a daemon, so that nothing can close/suspend the process.